# Tab is not rendering when changing I18nManager.forceRTL(true) in native-base in React -native

Tags: tabs, react-native, native-base

I am using Tab, Tabs from 'native-base'.

I am showing calendar in tab like

[image]

It is showing correct in English but when we change it Arabic by

```
I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
I18nManager.allowRTL(true);
```

app convert into RTL but when  I open this modal it shows blank first time , Like first screenshot.
And when we click on tab onChangeTab showing correct tab according to RTL but content is not changing.

content is showing  like before , means last tab is showing content like week in English and first tab is showing content like Date in English

[image]

code for showing Tab

```
<Tabs
onChangeTab={({ i }) => {
    console.log("current tab--",i)
    startDate=null;endDate=null;
    this.setState({ currentTab: i
        })
    //selectedDays:{}
    startDate=null;
    endDate=null;
}}
tabBarPosition={'top'}
tabBarUnderlineStyle={styles.tabBarUnderlineStyle}>
<Tab textStyle={styles.inActiveTextStyle}
    activeTextStyle={styles.activeTextStyle}
    heading={ <TabHeading style={{backgroundColor:'#f8f8f8'}}>

        {this.state.currentTab ==0 &&
        < TabHeadingComponents isCurrent={'1'}  cal_icon={require('../Resources/Images/DateEnable.png')} title={translate("date")}/>
        }
        {this.state.currentTab != 0 &&
        < TabHeadingComponents isCurrent={'0'}  cal_icon={require('../Resources/Images/DateDisable.png')} title={translate("date")}/>
        }
    </TabHeading>}>

    <View />
</Tab>

<Tab
    tabBarUnderlineStyle={styles.tabBarUnderlineStyle}
    textStyle={styles.inActiveTextStyle}
    activeTextStyle={styles.activeTextStyle}
    heading={<TabHeading style={{backgroundColor:'#f8f8f8'}}>

        {this.state.currentTab == 1 &&
        <TabHeadingComponents isCurrent={'1'} cal_icon={require('../Resources/Images/monthEnable.png')} title={translate("month")}/>

        }
        {this.state.currentTab != 1 &&
        <TabHeadingComponents isCurrent={'0'} cal_icon={require('../Resources/Images/monthDisable.png')} title={translate("month")}/>
        }



    </TabHeading>}>

    <View/>
</Tab>

<Tab

    textStyle={styles.inActiveTextStyle}
    activeTextStyle={styles.activeTextStyle}
    heading={ <TabHeading style={{backgroundColor:'#f8f8f8'}}>

        {this.state.currentTab == 2 &&
        <TabHeadingComponents isCurrent={'1'} cal_icon={require('../Resources/Images/weekEnable.png')} title={translate("week")}/>

        }
        {this.state.currentTab != 2 &&
        <TabHeadingComponents isCurrent={'0'} cal_icon={require('../Resources/Images/weekDisable.png')} title={translate("week")}/>
        }


    </TabHeading>}>

    <View/>
</Tab>
```

Comment: can you solve this?